# Python: Adding Time in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code where it is adds a header to my file. you can see in the header it adds; 'name', 'date' and 'time'.

what i am trying to attempted next is to add another line in the header called 'AddedTime'. this field needs to add 15 mins on top of the current time and output it out into the 'AddedTime' header.

Python code.

Comment: Are you trying to retroactively add the line to existing files, or are you just trying to figure out how to add a `timedelta` to a `datetime`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15))

2019-03-21 12:57:50.418277
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's quite simple with `datetime.timedelta`, just do an addition of 15 mins, and you could use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format the datetime output.

```
addedTime  = (stamp + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```